# Significato di "suli"

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *La Storia*, di Elsa Morante, ho letto queste parole pronunciate da Giuseppe, un personaggio proveniente dall'estremo sud calabrese:

> «Ma quale fango, Noruzza mia?! Lu fangu sta sulle mani bianche del proprietario e del banchiere! Lu fangu è la putrida società! Anarchia non è fango!! Anarchia è onore de lu mundu, nome santo, vero **suli** della nuova storia, rivoluzione immensa, *implacabbile*!!»

La mia domanda è sul vocabolo "suli", che non sono riuscita a trovare su nessun dizionario. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa?

Comment: Dal contesto della frase direi che potrebbe significare "sole" (nel senso di luce che illumina e guida;  si può usare anche _faro_ con un significato analogo).

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Questa tua ipotesi ha perfettamente senso! [Qui](http://m.dialettando.com/dizionario/detail/?id=20208) si afferma che nella Puglia è "soli" (non appare la Calabria, però).

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: [Qui](https://it.wikiquote.org/wiki/Proverbi_calabresi) si trova qualche proverbio calabrese in cui il termine "suli" viene tradotto come "sole". Se vuoi, puoi usarlo come fonte per scrivere una risposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In questa [raccolta di proverbi calabresi](https://it.wikiquote.org/wiki/Proverbi_calabresi#M) il vocabolo *"suli"* è tradotto come *"sole"*.

Dal contesto della frase (il personaggio sta facendo un elogio dell'anarchia), "sole" viene utilizzato in modo figurato, nel senso di luce che illumina, guida e dà senso alle cose, o anche nel senso di cosa talmente preziosa e splendente da abbagliare.